# How is md5 included/protected in php, c# and other applications?

Tags: c#, php, algorithm, md5

I want to know how php, c# has included the md5 hashing because how can php or c# include md5 hashing system without knowing the algorithm, and how have the managed to keep the algorithm secure, and does this mean that the people who made c# or php know the md5 algorithm?

Comment: md5 is not secure & is not meant tobe

Comment: @John - Any hashing and/or encryption algorithm that is useful is public knowlege.  You would be a fool to use any hashing/encryption algorithm you first don't understand yourself how it works.  This means the algorithm must have been review by the other people besides the author.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a need to keep the hash (or encryption) algorithm secret, then it is not really good.

The MD5 algorithm is available for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - It's down to the source code library included in the language build.

Secondly - MD5 is a one way algorithm,  It doesn't need to be secure, there is no 'key'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, md5 algorithm is public - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Anyone can independently implement it in any language.

While I am not sure what you mean by secure, assuming you are referring to using md5 as a password hash, md5 is not secure. If thats what you are planning, read [How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about encryption algorithms is that even if you know how it works you can't easily decrypt it. That's why most encryption algorithms are public, at least the ones deployed by c# and php. But md5 isn't really secure anymore, you better use AES.

Comment: MD5 isn't an encryption algorithm. AES is. They're not substitutes for each other.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has already said this, but I'll add this one thing... MD5 isn't meant to "obscure" things, really, It's really a way to "normalize" data.  No matter what you start with you end up with a 32 character [thing] that represents the original string. It's a fabulous way to make sure that the original string is what you expect it to be. That's why it's frequently used to compare files, since no matter what the original content of a file, it can still be represented with a 32 character string.  So, the answer to your question is really that the whole point is to simply make sure that it's the SAME algorithm in all these different languages so that you can count on the same result no matter where you convert your source string to its MD5 counterpart.